# Can't access MS Graph Email Attachment ContentBytes attribute

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I'm using the latest version of the MS Graph SDK (5.32.0).
I've seen examples on how to [download attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) but I cannot use the `ContentBytes` attribute.
My goal would be to save the attachment in a specific folder with: `File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, attachment.ContentBytes)` (`attachment.ContentBytes` is not usebale/doesn't exist for some reason when i try to call it but, it does exists when i check the [attachment attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHrGV.png))

My code for getting an attachment.

```cs
var attachment = await graphClient.Users["{userID}"].Messages["{msgId}"].Attachments["{attachmentId}"]
.GetAsync();
```

Comment: Are you are about the code? SDK v5 doesn't have Request() method. await graphClient.Users["{userID}"].Messages["{msgId}"].Attachments["{attachmentId}"]
.GetAsync(); Also try to cast attachment to FileAttachment => var fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked for me.
And I'm sorry I included the wrong code example. I changed it.